# AVAudioUnits and offline rendering

Tags: ios8, avfoundation, osx-yosemite

Is it possible to set properties on the new AVAudioUnits, and particularly an equivalent of the old kAudioUnitProperty_OfflineRender property?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, I think you need to:

1. Grab the underlying audiounit [via AVAudioUnit API](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioUnit_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioUnit/audioUnit)
2. [Set the property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioUnitSetProperty) on the audiounit via a call like:

`AudioUnitSetProperty(myAudioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_OfflineRender, kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &isOffline, sizeof(isOffline));`